# Angular - Errors in ng build -aot

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I created an application with Angular-cli, and when I run `ng serve` or `ng build` everything works fine, I don't have any error; but when I run `ng build -aot` I have the following errors :

> ERROR in Child compilation failed:
>       Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the 
>       corresponding plugin
>
> refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin 
>       for the usage example at Object.module.exports.pitch 
>       :
>       Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin
>
> refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:...\src'
>       @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
>       @ multi ./src/main.ts

I tried looking on Github but I didn't understand what could be the problem. I also tried to update all modules and angular-cli but it made it worse (application not working anymore and building was taking more than an hour with new errors)

Any ideas where this might come from and how to resolve these errors ?

**Versions :**

- @angular/cli: 1.0.0
- node: 6.10.1
- os: win32 x64
- @angular/common: 4.1.3
- @angular/compiler: 4.1.3
- @angular/core: 4.1.3
- @angular/forms: 4.1.3
- @angular/http: 4.1.3
- @angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
- @angular/platform-browser/dynamic: 4.1.3
- @angular/router: 4.1.3
- @angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3

--

**EDIT -** So I followed [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) : install @angular/platform-server, create a tsconfig-aot.json, run `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json` and edit my main.ts from

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

to

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

and now I have only one error :

> Tried to find boostrap code, but could not.Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
>
> at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain C:...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:128:11
>
> at AotPlugin._setupOptions C:...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:142:50
>
> at new AotPlugin C:...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:26:14
>
> at _createAotPlugin C:...\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:55:12
>
> atObject.exports.getNonAotConfig C:...\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:70:19
>
> at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig C:...\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs.js:27:37
>
> at Class.run C:...\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:37:98
>
> at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port C:...\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:103:26
>
> at process._tickCallback internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7

Comment: what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I am using typescript 2.2.0

Comment: aot flag is removed from @angular/cli, now you just need to run ng build --prod, it will build using aot compilation.